# How do you update range of formula in Google Sheets when you add a row?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I have a column in a Google sheet that has numbers in cells A1-A5. In A7 I show the sum of cells A1-A5 using `=SUM(A1:A5)`. I want to be able to add/remove cells from the A1-A5 range and have A7 behave accordingly.

For example, I want to add a number in A6 by clicking "insert row below" on row 5, and have the sum in A7 move down to A8 and have its formula update to `=SUM(A1:A6)`.

So here's what I have right now:

[image]

...and here's the kind of thing I want to be able to add:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

instead of your `=SUM(A1:A5)` use this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()-1))
```

this will allow you to get sum of all above regardless if you add or delete rows